# How to set state for UWP element?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows

I have a button whose states changes depending on some criteria., eg, change colour, size, enabled/disabld, when a toggle button is on. My goal is to encapsulate the states so that we can do something like this:

```
 if (toggleButton.IsOn) btnName.state = State1;
 else btnName.state = State2;
```

Where we define State 1 and State 2 (maybe in XAML?).

Is this possible to do with UWP?

Comment: _"Is this possible to do with UWP?"_ -- of course. The XAML-based APIs all expect you to separate your business logic and UI using MVVM-style programming. Depending on what `state` actually is, you will want either to use triggers in the button styles, or a property in the view model that you adjust according to the toggle button state. Given how vague your question is, it's simply too broad to actually answer. You'll need to show exactly what you're doing, what you've tried, and what specifically you're having trouble with, using a [mcve] and a clear, detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke a certain state of a control by using `VisualStateManager`. For example, if you want to manually let the `ToggleSwitch` go to its `On` state, you can write -

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(MyToggleSwitch, "On", true);
```

**But don't do this.** Because this only set the state *visually*, the underlying `IsOn` property is still `False`.

Actually, by setting `IsOn` to `True`, the `On` state will be automatically applied. This is because inside the `ToggleStates` visual state group in the `ToggleSwitch`'s [default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299159.aspx), there's an `On` state with a bunch of `Storyboard`s like the following -

```
<VisualState x:Name="On">
  <Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                     To="24"
                     Duration="0" />
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

These `Storyboard`s will begin whenever `IsOn` is set to `True`. This triggering logic is encapsulated inside `ToggleSwitch`'s code. So when you want to define your own visual states for your custom controls, you will need to manually hook up the state properties (e.g. `IsChecked`, `IsSelected`, `IsOn`, `IsEnabled`) with their corresponding states, so when other people are using your controls, they can simply update them and expect the right states to be applied.